# How to create a base API project and use this endpoint in other API projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a situation where I have multiple API projects in one solution. What I would like to do now is to create a base project with endpoints, which are available for all the existing API projects.

So, for example:

The base project has endpoint `/api/contact`

All the other API projects don't have this endpoint. I would like to 'merge' the `/api/contact` endpoint with all the other projects, so these other project now also have this endpoint.

Of course I can create a new site and host the base project as an independent site, but this gets a new address, I want this endpoint to be available on the other projects, so it keeps the existing host.

I know I need to scan or add the base project somehow to 'add' it to another project, but I have no idea how.

PS: I am using .net framework; not .net core.

Comment: I solved a similar issue in my organisation by making the "base" project into a Nuget package which can then be installed into any other project (ours is for MVC but the same principle could be used for an API project) - the nuget essentially deploys a .cs controller file into the target project which contains the action methods for the shared endpoints (e.g. all our apps contain standard "provide feedback" functionality), plus a DLL containing the models, types etc and (in our case but probably not yours) other content resources such as views, JS, CSS etc. It works nicely.

Comment: (Note that the controller is deployed as a raw .cs file which then becomes part of the target project, rather than delivering it as compiled code. I forget precisely how we did it now without going to look it up but we also made it automatically replace the namespace of the incoming controller class with the default namespace of the target project during installation, so you don't have to make any manual changes before it will compile and work properly.)